# Multi thread in lightning component script

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, locker-service

im looking for some method to divide thread in my lightning component JS.

As far as I know is JS running on single thread.
but web.Worker function can be alternative.

i tried to use `web.worker` .. but locker service blocking me. `[undefined]`

is there **any way to divide thread in locker service ??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workers are forbidden by Lightning at this time ([Locker API Viewer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer)). There's no indication of when, or if, such functionality might be available. For now, you will have to use a combination of promises and asynchronous callbacks (e.g. setTimeout or events). The specific technique necessary will depend on the goal you're trying to achieve.